# Is there a correlation between support and F1 score?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I was thinking if F1 score is usually correlated with support in classification problems. In theory, shouldn't the F1 score increase for a label if there is more support? Why does this not always happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does the numbers in the classification report of sklearn mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117654/what-does-the-numbers-in-the-classification-report-of-sklearn-mean)

Comment: I do know what each of these mean...what I would like to know if it is common that support effects f1 score and whether there is a direct correlation

Comment: Having never heard the nomenclature "F1 score", for a moment I thought the question concerned the relationship between fan support of F1 teams (as in Formula 1) and their results at the end of the championship

Comment: The support is the number of times each class appears in your *data*... Why would that necessarily correlate positively with a measure of performance of your *model*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support only relates to the ground truth. It is the same whathever your result is. On the contrary, the F1-score is computed from your actual scores thus depends from your results.

Thus, there is no direct link between support and F1-score in theory.

You can have an indirect  link if the model performs better on a particular class. In that case, the more sample in that class, the larger the support and the higher the F1-score. But it is really due to the fact that

- the model performs well on that class thus the F1-score increases
- the class is larger thus the support is larger